# QGIS segmentation fault related to numpy on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, numpy

I'm running QGIS 2.14 on Ubuntu 14.04 and everything's been working just fine until I upgraded a few Python packages via pip this afternoon. Since doing that, QGIS crashes with a segmentation fault when I try to start it. I don't get any error message, but when I look at the system log it says:

> qgis.bin[9382]: segfault at 7efeea8031a0 ip 00007efeea8031a0 sp 00007ffc54ffdfa8 error 15 in multiarray.so[7efeea7fb000+f000]

Numpy was among the packages I upgraded, and I believe multiarray.so is part of numpy. I've tried uninstalling `sudo pip uninstall numpy`. That leaves the apt `python-numpy` package (version 1.8). Then when I try to start QGIS, I get an error saying my version of numpy is too old. I've also tried `sudo pip install 'numpy==1.10.4'` to downgrade, but I still get that same multiarray.so seg fault.

Please help me if you can. I've got a massive deadline looming, and this is a really bad time to be having these sorts of issues.

Comment: I see this as a bug on Ubuntu Launchpad: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-numpy/+question/292733 - maybe not related to QGIS so much as Ubuntu?

Comment: I can't find `multiarry.x86_64.so` anywhere on my system, so I don't think my problem is directly related to that bug. I think the problem is related to the fact that I've got both the `apt-get` `python-numpy` version 1.8 and the `pip` numpy version on my system. I'm just too much of linux dunce to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: you might try a sudo apt-get purge python-numpy then see if the pip-installed version is still there by doing a pip list and if not do a fresh install via pip...?

Comment: I considered that, but apt-get told me that it would remove a whole bunch of other stuff that depends on numpy if I removed `python-numpy`. I think the root of the problem is that `python-numpy` for Ubuntu 14.04 is still v1.8. I'm working to finish my PhD thesis at the moment. I made the small edits to a map I needed with a graphics program (lame). Once I hand in my thesis, I'll probably just upgrade Ubuntu to 16.04. I'm pretty sure that will fix it (`python-numpy` 1.11 is available for 16.04), but I don't want to upgrade before hand-in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hope you get everything finished ok... good luck!